# Unable to use backward hooks in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I am trying to implement [The Lottery Ticket Hypothesis: Finding Sparse, Trainable Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.03635v5) in pytorch using backward hooks to stop incoming gradient for freezing some weights. Everything seems to work fine when adding the hooks are added manually but it shows an error when I try to do the same in a loop. The mask_dict is a dictionary with layer name as keys and boolean mask as values. The mask is created by setting the lowest pr_value% l1-norm of weights to be zero. Below is the code

```py
def l1norm_mask(model, pr_value, prune_large=False):
    mask_dict={}
    for name, module in model.named_modules():
        if 'linear' in name:
            t = module.weight
            bottomk = torch.topk(torch.abs(t).view(-1), k=round(pr_value*t.nelement()), largest=prune_large)
            clone = t.clone().detach()
            clone.view(-1)[bottomk.indices] = 0
            mask_dict[name] = clone.bool()
    return mask_dict


def apply_mask(model, mask_dict):
    for name, module in model.named_modules():
        if 'linear' in name:
            print('')
            module.weight.data *= mask_dict[name]
            print('module name is:', name, 'and weight size is:', module.weight.size())
            print('corresponding tensor is:', mask_dict[name].shape)
            module.weight.register_hook(lambda x: x*mask_dict[name])  #<-- problem here

#     model.linear1.weight.register_hook(lambda x: x*mask_dict['linear1'])
#     model.linear2.weight.register_hook(lambda x: x*mask_dict['linear2'])
#     model.linear3.weight.register_hook(lambda x: x*mask_dict['linear3'])

mask = l1norm_mask(model, 0.60)
apply_mask(model, mask)
mask.keys()
```

By printing some tensor shapes, it seems that they are all compatible for element-wise multiplication. The output is:

```
module name is: linear1 and weight size is: torch.Size([300, 784])
corresponding tensor is: torch.Size([300, 784])

module name is: linear2 and weight size is: torch.Size([100, 300])
corresponding tensor is: torch.Size([100, 300])

module name is: linear3 and weight size is: torch.Size([10, 100])
corresponding tensor is: torch.Size([10, 100])

dict_keys(['linear1', 'linear2', 'linear3'])
```

Trying to train the network gives the following error:

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-2e752da442fd> in <module>
----> 1 losses = [update(x,y,3e-3) for x,y in data.train_dl]

<ipython-input-18-2e752da442fd> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 losses = [update(x,y,3e-3) for x,y in data.train_dl]

<ipython-input-17-ca0fbe546149> in update(x, y, lr)
      3     y_hat = model(x)
      4     loss = loss_fn(y_hat, y)
----> 5     loss.backward()
      6     opt.step()
      7     opt.zero_grad()

~/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    164                 products. Defaults to ``False``.
    165         """
--> 166         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    167 
    168     def register_hook(self, hook):

~/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
     97     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
     98         tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
---> 99         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    100 
    101 

<ipython-input-16-46b511a78892> in <lambda>(x)
     35             print('module name is:', name, 'and weight size is:', module.weight.size())
     36             print('correspoding tensor is:', mask_dict[name].shape)
---> 37             module.weight.register_hook(lambda x: x*mask_dict[name])
     38 
     39 #     model.linear1.weight.register_hook(lambda x: x*mask_dict['linear1'])

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (300) must match the size of tensor b (100) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

Update: I modified the code a bit and printed the the incoming gradient shape and shape of the mask I am passing in the loop. It seems that the way backward hooks are called, it always takes the first value ie ‘linear1’(=name) so same mask is getting passed to all the gradients resulting in mis-match matrix size error. Here’s the output I got:

```
shape of grad torch.Size([10, 100])  mask-shape torch.Size([10, 100])

shape of grad torch.Size([100, 300])  mask-shape torch.Size([10, 100])

shape of grad torch.Size([300, 784])  mask-shape torch.Size([10, 100])

shape of grad torch.Size([10, 100])  mask-shape torch.Size([10, 100])

shape of grad torch.Size([100, 300])  mask-shape torch.Size([10, 100])

shape of grad torch.Size([300, 784])  mask-shape torch.Size([10, 100])
```

and this repeats on…